# Deselect all checkboxes except mandatory/disabled checkboxes Angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, void, deselect

HTML:

```html
                   <mat-selection-list #selectedColumns [(ngModel)] ="selectedOptions">
                   <div class= "content-section">
                   <mat-expansion-panel>
                   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                   <mat-panel-title> Account<mat-panel-title>
                   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                   <mat-list-option class= "download-columns" 
                   checkboxPosition="before"
                  *ngFor= "let column of singleNodeColumns" 
                   [selected]="column.template.Mandatory"
                   [disabled]="column.template.Mandatory" 
                   [value]="column.template">
                   <div class= "down load-columns-text">
                    <span> {{column.template.Name}}</span>
```

TS:

```js
      DeSelectionAll()
         { this.selectedColumns.selectedOption.clear(); }
```

This will deselect all checkboxes but it also deselects the `column.template.Mandatory` which I do not want. Please Help.

Comment: please format your questions using code blocks so that they are readable.

Comment: I suggest that you set your `selectedOptions` variable instead of calling `clear()`.

Comment: @JakeSmith can you  please explain or give an example. Not sure how that would work.

Comment: I would take a look at @Nehal's answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the component.ts file, so not sure what your `selectedOptions` and `column.template.Mandatory` look like. My best guess is, you have to run a filter, to remove all items, except the ones that match with mandatory items.

Something like:

```
DeSelectionAll() { 
    this.selectedColumns.selectedOption = 
        this.selectedColumns.selectedOption.filter(item => item === column.template.Mandatory); 
}
```

If `column.template.Mandatory` is an array, than you have looks for the match with the `column.template.Mandatory` array:

```
DeSelectionAll() { 
    this.selectedColumns.selectedOption = 
        this.selectedColumns.selectedOption.filter(item => column.template.Mandatory.findIndex(x => x === item) > -1); 
}
```

If `selectedOptions` and `column.template.Mandatory` have identifier fields like 'id', you can run above function with `x.id === item.id`